# Setting up Python script with Socket.io to change Three.js animation

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, socket.io

I made a small environment with Three.js that loads a 3D model and is able to randomly change the animations of said model. Now I need to connect this environment with a Python script that is going to change the animation calling a certain function in my JavaScript, for this I'm trying to use [Socket.io](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) to create a socket and try to call this function in my JS code. Sadly I haven't been able to connect both programs as I'm not really sure how to do what I'm planning.

Python server code (emitted jump inside connect just to test if it was working, it's not.)

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp')
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connect ", sid)
    print("Sending command to js")
    sio.emit('jump', data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

Javascript Code (Deleted most of the function's internals just to make it shorter)

```
(function main() {

init(); 

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    ...

    var socket = io.connect('http://0.0.0.0:8080');
}

function update() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }

  update();

  socket.on('jump', function(data) {
    playAnimation();
});

  function playAnimation() {
    ...
  }


})();
```

My questions are:

- **How can I create a minimal socket connection in Python using socket.io to call the JS function playAnimation?**
- **If I wanted to call different functions according to my Python console input, what should I do to accomplish this?**
- **If update() is permanently looping, where should I place the event detection?**
- **Is Socket.io overkill for this and should I instead use other library or the included Python sockets?**

Thank you.

Comment: I removed the [three.js] tag because even though your project is using Three.js, your question is about python and socket.io.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html